# Velocity does not resolve variable in foreach loop

Tags: java, foreach, velocity

I have very simple velocity template:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Velocity template</title>
    </head>
    <body>      
        #foreach($p in $products)
            $p.name
        #end        
    </body>
</html>
```

and code that processes it:

```
VelocityEngine engine = new VelocityEngine();
engine.init();
Template t = engine.getTemplate("./src/com/irbis/dms/velocity/template.html");
VelocityContext ctx = new VelocityContext();

Product p1 = new Product("fridge");
Product p2 = new Product("sofa");
Product p3 = new Product("table");
Product p4 = new Product("chair");

List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
products.add(p1);
products.add(p2);
products.add(p3);
products.add(p4);

ctx.put("products", products);
...

class Product implements Serializable {

    private String name;

    public Product() {
    }

    public Product(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

but after the execution I have the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Velocity template</title>
    </head>
    <body>      
                    $p.name
                    $p.name
                    $p.name
                    $p.name
    </body>
</html>
```

It works fine if I put into the context String, Integer etc.
Where is the error? I use velocity 1.5.

Comment: did you declare `class Product` as public?

Comment: Thank you very much! The problem was that `class Product` was declared with default access. Now it works fine.

Comment: Marco, could you please post your answer? so I can mark it as accepted

Comment: if it makes you happy ;)

Comment: This is my first time use Velocity and this is a wonder find, Thank Marco

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to declare your `Product` class as `public` or otherwise you can not use it in your template.

```
public class Product implements Serializable {
```

Comment: Pretty crappy behavior from Velocity, I'd dare say.

Comment: the problem is Velocity's silence. Would be easier if it complaint about such things...

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is not visible as it is private, use getName() and let us know.

Comment: Learnt something new then!